# Is the category of projections interesting?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $C$ be a category and let $C'$ be the wide subcategory whose maps are projections, that is maps in $C$ which belong to some limiting cone (over a discrete base). Since limiting cones compose, $C'$ is indeed a subcategory of $C$ (containing all isomorphisms of $C$).

For instance, if $C$ is the category of finite sets, a mapping $f:A\to B$ is in $C'$
if and only if all fibers $f^{-1}y$ have the same cardinality. Thus the posetal reflection of $C'$ is equivalent to the poset of natural numbers ordered by divisibility. Note that this $C'$ has not finite products (although a terminal set is terminal also in $C'$).
Or (dually) one can consider topological spaces obtaining the category of embeddings which are summands.

My question:

> has this notion been already considered?

> are there interesting instances?

Comment: We've found some use for the finite sets example that you mention in categorical probability, see Definition 3.1.4 in [A Probability Monad as the Colimit of Spaces of Finite Samples](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.05363).

Comment: I would not consider it to be a subcategory but rather a class of morphisms. In a category with finitary products, this would be the smallest class of morphisms containing the isomorphisms and the projections to the terminal object and closed under pullback. In particular, in a category with pullbacks, this is the smallest class of fibrations making it a category of fibrant objects.

Comment: @ZhenLin, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438153/is-the-category-of-projections-interesting#comment1129696_438153), what is the difference between a [wide subcategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/wide+subcategory) and a class of morphisms closed under composition?

Comment: You might say it’s a difference in perspective. Personally I don’t find it useful to think of a class of fibrations as a category in its own right, so why should I think of it as a subcategory at all?

Comment: Because "wide subcategory" is shorter than "class of morphisms containing all identities and closed under composition"?  (-: